# How to trigger display of ProgressTemplate in UpdatePanel?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Working on an asp.net website. In one of the pages I am using an UpdatePanel with a ProgressTemplate inside of it (it contains an "updating.gif"). On the same page I also have a jQuery/bootstrap date-range-picker.

When I select a date range I do a postback using ___doPostBack. Everything is working fine, the postback, etc..., but the problem is updating.gif never appears. But, I'd like it to (at least when it's "processing").

QUESTION: How could I do this, either with javascript, in Page_Load, etc? Thanks!

The Update panel is defined as....

```
       <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1_UpdateProgress1" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1">
        <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="ajaxUpdatePanel">
            </div>
            <div style="position: absolute; padding: 30px;" class="updatingContainer">
                <img src="../Images/updating.gif" alt="Updating" />
            </div>
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
        <ContentTemplate>
                 :
                 :
```

The date-range-picker is defined as....

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="daterange" name="daterange" 
    class="jQuery_DateRangePicker" runat="server" Width="110px"></asp:TextBox>
```

When a date is selected I do this (among other things)....

```
__doPostBack('daterange', '');
```

I also tried wrapping the javascript code in this but nothing showed....

```
$get('<%= UpdatePanel1_UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>').style.display = 'block';
 // do all the processing
$get('<%= UpdatePanel1_UpdateProgress1.ClientID %>').style.display = 'none';
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the ajaxUpdatePanel used for in there?  My guess would be that it's got something to do with that, though not sure since it doesn't really seem to be doing anything.

In theory the progress template is called during the server side call is working for the specified update panel.

Check out this [link](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=227) to see some examples.

Comment: This page as a gridview and some other controls which take a while to load. One of the columns is a data and I'm using this data-range-picker in the header row of the column to select/filter the data in the gridview. @Fenrir88

Comment: Ok, so there's a postback when daterange's text changes? Have you tried doing the postback with asp method rather than JS's  doPostBack? Like OnTextChanged="serverMethod"

Comment: No I haven't tried that. Do you mean code behind the aspx, using vb.net/c#? When I set autopostback=true it seems to hang the page. I'm just wondering about my original question. Possible to show progress gif while the javascript is processing?

Comment: Yes, with c# code. You add the line OnTextChanged="C#MethodNameHere" to the textbox and it will/should call the method to the server, which should activate the updateprogress.  Regarding the showing of gif during JS processing I don't think it can be approached in the same way. Probably you'd have to use full Javascript for that, including the creation of a div that contains the gif and the methods for showing and hiding.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use AjaxToolkit? If Yes, then

```
<ajaxToolkit:ModalPopupExtender ID="modalPopup" runat="server" TargetControlID="UpdateProgress"
PopupControlID="UpdateProgress" BackgroundCssClass="modalPopup" />
```

Please check for complete example:
[update panel and progress bar example by code](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2010/10/how-to-show-progressbar-during.html)